# YouTube Analytics API - Content owner reports

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So, I am trying to use Monetary Analytics API, to fetch earnings report for given YouTube channel.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_reports

However, to use this API, the following is required:

> To retrieve a content owner report, set the ids parameter value in
>   your API request to contentOwner==OWNER_NAME, where OWNER_NAME
>   specifies the content owner's ID. Ask your partner manager if you are
>   unsure of the value.

So, after browsing online, I've found unofficial documentation, that may be what I'm looking for.
http://jump.techden.in/developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/contentOwners/list

So I added `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner` scope, reauthenticated, and made this request:

```
  def list_content_owners
    conn = FaradayAdapter.new("https://www.googleapis.com").conn

    params = {
      :fetchMine => true,
      :key => DEVELOPER_KEY
    }
    resp = conn.get do |req|
      req.url "/youtube/partner/v1/contentOwners", params
      req.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{@token}"
    end
    debugger

    return nil unless resp.try(:status) == 200
    JSON.parse resp.body || nil
  end
```

However, I get the following 403 error:

> (rdb:1) resp.body "{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n
>   \"domain\": \"usageLimits\",\n    \"reason\":
>   \"accessNotConfigured\",\n    \"message\": \"Access Not Configured\"\n
>   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 403,\n  \"message\": \"Access Not Configured\"\n
>   }\n}\n"

I've looked into my developer console https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and I already have all YouTube related API's enabled. There is no special partner API listing available.

So, if I can't get `contentOwner id`, whats the point of Analytics API?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer here?

Answer (score 0):

As clearly described in the page you were referring to : https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_reports

contentOwner is related to Content ID API and and only available to few partners. Make sure you have this API available in your console or ask your partner manager if you are eligible for this API.

Comment: Some of them. Ask your YT contact about it.